# Magento 2.4.2 - Forbidden error on Nginx because of no index file in root directory

Tags: magento2, nginx, permissions, magento2.4.2, http-status-403

I am getting a 403 forbidden error while opening my website URL on the browser. After so much research I have found that the index file is missing from the Magento root directory and it is moved to the pub directory.
 Can anyone tell me how to solve this error?
 How can I forward the index request to the pub directory?

Comment: are you creating a virtual host in ngnix?

Comment: yes I am using a virtual host in Nginx

Answer (score 1):

The issue should be solved if you go to the nginx configurations and set the `root` directive to point to the `<magento_folder>/pub`. Don't forget to reload nginx afterwards.

Some resources:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html#a-note-about-nginx
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html#1-edit-your-server-configuration